# Returning void from a double function?

Tags: c, function, return, void

I have a function which is a double and normally returns the new value for a variable, but sometimes I don't want to change the variable and I would like to signal that by returning a special value, for example void. Is that possible?

For example:

```
double GetNewValue(int feature) {
    switch( feature ) {
        case TYPE1:
            return void; // or maybe use return; here?
        case TYPE2:
            return 2.343;
        default:
            return featureDefaultValue;
    }
}
```

PS: I know I can use NaN, but I already use it as a valid value with another meaning (not yet a number is available).

/EDIT: Thank you all for your answers, these 3 answers are all applicable to my problem and are all equally valid. I struggle right now in choosing which one I'm going to use (which will be the one I will accept, but I wish I could accept them all!).

Comment: You could use `NaN`. `void` makes no sense since it's something similar to a type, not to a value.

Comment: But then how can I check it? Is it possible to affect to a variable and check if the returned value is none?

Comment: btw. there are many different NaNs. In principle you could use different NaNs for different meanings, but that's probably a bad idea.

Comment: Regarding your post-scriptum, “I know I can use NaN, but I already use it as a valid value with another meaning (not yet a number is available”, do you know that there are **several** NaNs? You would just have to use a different one from the one you use for “no number available yet”. Google “NaN payload” for details.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think it is only a bad idea to use different NaNs if you intend to do computations that involve several of them. Then you may get any of the original NaNs as result (AFAIK each IEEE 754 operation is defined as returning one of the NaNs it receives as argument if some of its arguments are NaN). Using several NaNs as placeholders is fine.

Comment: Indeed later in my code I do computations with those NaNs (but mainly by filtering them out, but it has an explicit use in interpolating missing values), thus why I want to avoid using NaNs for any other purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you need to return two things from a function, not one. A common way to do so is taking a pointer to the return value, and returning a yes/no flag to indicate the validity of the actual `double`:

```
int GetNewValue(double *res, int feature) {
    switch( feature ) {
    case TYPE1:
        return 0; // no change to res
    case TYPE2:
        *res = 2.343;
        return 1;
    default:
        *res = featureDefaultValue;
        return 1;
}
```

Now instead of doing this

```
double res = GetNewValue(myFeature);
```

the users of your function would need to do this:

```
double res;
if (GetNewValue(&res, myFeature)) {
    // use res here - it's valid
} else {
    // do not use res here - it's not been set
}
```

Comment: I accept this answer because in my case I have separated the GetNewValue() function and SetNewValue() function (the latter only modifying the value if GetNewValue() returns something), so it is more clean to use this approach. My only regret is that other users will have to always add an appropriate return statement (I wanted to minimize a maximum the complexity), but it's a minor drawback of this implementation, and is more clean than using pointers in my case.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to pass the result variable as a pointer:

```
void AssignNewValue(int feature, double* result)
{
    switch( feature ) {
    case TYPE1:
        return;
    case TYPE2:
        *result = 2.343;
        break;
    default:
        *result = featureDefaultValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Used like:

```
double featureValue = 42.0;

/* ... */

AssignNewValue(feature, &featureValue);
```

Comment: How is this different from just returning a double?

Comment: I didn't think I had left that as an "exercise for the reader"...but if the caller passes `TYPE1` then the value of `featureValue` is preserved. Hence this is different than just returning a double.

Comment: Yes, it does preserve the old value of *result. But it does not tell the caller what happened at all without a result code.

Comment: Indeed there is no explicit signaling, but for my application I only need an implicit signaling. This is actually a very good answer. I don't know which one to chose!

Comment: @bobobobo: I made assumptions about the calling code which the other answers did not make.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an "optional" return parameter.  You don't seem to (and rightly so) want to use 0.0 as the "no value" result because that means 0.0 can't be used for an actual value.

2 good solutions you sometimes see for this is to either use a "result code", or to use a *pointer* as the return result. (Pointers are more complicated). I'll start with #1 first:

## 1. Result codes

```
// definitions for result codes
#define FAIL 0
#define OK 1

int GetNewValue(int feature, double *result) {
    switch( feature ) {
        case TYPE1:
            *result = 0.0 ;
            return FAIL ; // caller of the function should recognize
                          // the call "failed"
        case TYPE2:
            *result = 200.0 ;
            return OK ;
        default:
            *result = 47.0 ;
            return OK;
    }
}

// use:
double feature ;
int result = GetNewValue( 5, &feature ) ;
if( result == OK )
{
    // do something with "feature"
}
```

## 2. Using pointers

```
double* GetNewValue(int feature) {
    switch( feature ) {
        case TYPE1:
            return NULL ; // NO POINTER means FAIL
        case TYPE2:
            return new double(200) ;
        default:
            return new double( 47 ) ;
    }
}

// use:
double* result = GetNewValue( 5 ) ;
if( result != NULL )
{
    // result had a value, so you can use it
}
```

The gotcha with pointers is you need to remember to `delete` the `result`

```
delete result ; // when done with pointer that was created
                // with `new`, you must `delete` it after
                // otherwise you'll get a memory leak
```

Comment: Very nice answer, particularly the second method using pointers, which throw away the need of returning another value in addition to the value, but I can't use pointers because of my current project's guidelines. But I will keep this method in my books, thank's!